# Why is the setField code changing appearance

Tags: itext, itextpdf

I am using

```
form.setField(fm_form + "[0].Page1[0].SEXID[0]", 1 )
```

to set an **Acrofield** in a form.
Is there a reason why it is changing the appearance from **round** sunken radio button to **square** radio with check, but not consistently??

[image: original]

[image: filled]

[image: selected]

Comment: If the appearance of the different states is defined for each widget annotation, then there is no reason why circles would become squares or vice versa: only the appearance defined for that specific state can be used. If no appearance is defined, the PDF viewer is completely free to choose whichever appearance it prefers. So the question is: does your PDF define appearances? I guess not... (This is probably not an iText issue, this is a general PDF issue.)

Comment: Bruno - they were created in LiveCycle with the artwork layer coming from InDesign. The all are set with attributes there of sunken circle with button style of circle. Reader is Acrobat DC or DC Pro. I will check with RUPS... And here is there problem with using this method of support rather than the list - someone has down-voted the question when to me it is a perfectly valid question to ask.

Comment: I up-voted to compensate. People who down-vote should at least post a comment explaining *why* they down-voted.